# How to run Background process in ASP.Net web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, background-process

I want to execute some of the function in my web application without intimating the user about the running process just like background process in windows application.

I want to trigger background process when user click and want to send some data to these function too.

Can any one suggest me how this could be performed?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349139/Running-a-background-service-in-a-Web-Application

Comment: already tried this but this not work in my case because i want to trigger background process when user click and wan to send some data to these function too

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article613-background-processes-in-asp-net-web-applications.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            timing();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }

    public void timing()
    {
        string tt = DateTime.Now.ToString("tt");
        string t = "";
        if (tt == "AM")
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            if ((hour >= 0) & (hour <= 11))
            {
                t = "GOOD MORNING";
            }
        }
        else if (tt == "PM")
        {
            int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
            if ((hour >= 12) & (hour <= 15))
            {
                t = "GOOD AFTERNOON";
            }
            else if ((hour >= 16) & (hour <= 23))
            {
                t = "GOOD EVENING";
            }
        }
        Label1.Text = t;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


//SOURCE:

<%@ Page Language="C#" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="background.aspx.cs" Inherits="background" %> //Async="true"
```

Comment: i see the code is neat and sleek, but u need to mention as where this code need to be implemented.

Comment: This code looks nice. But there's no explanation of it nor is there a definition of background worker. Is it imported from .Net? Did you write the class yourself? These are things people need to know otherwise you leave it open for interpretation and therefore failures and errors thusly making others regard this question with distrust and uncertainty which will hurt your reputation. Please fix it and let me know when you have  and I'll vote up instead of down.

Answer (score 0):

Though it solves a more complex problem (how to do this when using IoC where object lifetimes are scoped to requests) the AsyncRunner class from this article is a good starting point.

[Start background tasks from MVC actions using Autofac](http://aboutcode.net/2010/11/01/start-background-tasks-from-mvc-actions-using-autofac.html)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can follow these links and get an idea about how to approach the requirement.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article613-background-processes-in-asp-net-web-applications.aspx

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/137330/Run-a-background-job-in-ASP-NET