# How to call a web service in "fire and forget" way from ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, asynchronous

I have a web service that I want to call from one of my asp.net classes.
I can call my web service successfully.But now I need to call this service asynchronously. I need to call it and NOT wait for the service to complete execution. I don't need to process a response from the service and don't need to verify if the service executed successfully. All I want is to be able to call the service and be free to do other things.

Comment: You didn't show us the code for `PerformTaskAsync()`.  Are you sure that it is actually executing asynchronously?

Comment: Also note that you are wrapping the object on which you are calling `PerformTaskAsync()` in a `using` block, which seems problematic; either you leave the `using` block's scope before the task is completed, or it waits for the task to complete before it leaves the `using` block's scope, neither of which is desirable.  Have you considered simply spinning off this whole thing into its own thread, or using a `BackgroundWorker`?  Or maybe using `async` `await`?

Comment: Tried **async await**, but the browser still waits for the service to complete execution. Haven't tried a BackgroundWorker yet.

Comment: If you're trying to run this code on an ASP.NET server, you may need to stand up a Windows Service, or some similar mechanism that decouples it from the ASP.NET thread you're trying to run the code on.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601815 and http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/

Comment: But isn't that the point of calling a web service asynchronously? Maybe I'm getting mixed up here...

Comment: See also http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=948

Comment: @Administrateur - "call XXX asynchronously from ASP.Net application" commonly means "call, release thread, on call completion resume request handling, than return result to browser/caller", you are looking for "fire and forget" behavior which is not recommended to be done by ASP.Net process due to possibility to lose results/fact that it never finished.

Comment: See also http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: Administrateur - I've changed title to use what I think better term for expected behavior, feel free to revert/improve.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thanks for the clarification. I think the "fire and forget" method will work for me, as I only need to call the service and not worry if it ever finished execution. Another application constantly checks if processes are pending.

Comment: Have you looked at `IsOneWay=true`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isoneway(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Tim: Wow. That's all it was missing. Please add your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to implement a fire-and-forget approach is to use the `IsOneWay` property on the `OperationContract` attribute, like this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
public void SomeMethod(string someValue);
```

When set to true, the operation won't return a message.  Note that methods marked as one-way cannot have return types or `ref` or `out` parameters (which makes sense).  It also should not be confused with asynchronous calls, because it's not the same thing (in fact, a one-way call can block on the client if it takes a while to get a connection, for example).

See [OperationContractAttribute.IsOneWay Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.isoneway%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You need to consume web service asynchronously.
Goto and check

```
AddServiceReference -> Advance -> generate asynchronous operations.
```

after this async callback events will be available to you for every method
Suppose you have ABC method in you service when you will consume it by as sync these methods will be available to you in your application

```
1>ABC (fire and wait for output)
2>ABCAsync(fire and forget)
3>ABC callback event(get fired <if ABCAsync is called> when data available in your application)
```

Comment: Already done that. The title was revised. I'm looking for ways to implement a "fire/forget" scenario using a web service.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885132(v=vs.110).aspx

this is another way to do it, check it out.